# Jackson csv writer doesn't use correct column separator

Tags: java, jackson

I'm trying to write a CSV file using Jackson 2.2.2 (especially jackson-dataformat-csv) but i can't get it to use the ';' as fileseparator.

i'm using the following code to initialize the writer:

```
CsvMapper mapper = new CsvMapper();
CsvSchema schema = mapper.schemaFor(MyObject.class);
schema = schema.withColumnSeparator(CSV_COLUMN_SEPARATOR);

ObjectWriter myObjectWriter = mapper.writer(schema);
```

To create the csv i do something like the following:

```
FileOutputStream tempFileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(tempFile);
BufferedOutputStream bufferedOutputStream = new BufferedOutputStream(tempFileOutputStream, STREAM_BUFFER_SIZE);
writerOutputStream = new OutputStreamWriter(bufferedOutputStream, FILE_ENCODING);

myObjectWriter.writeValue(writerOutputStream, listOfMyObjects);
```

However the resulting file still uses the default ',' as column separator. When i check the object with the debugger the ';' is set as separator in the object so i guess it should work. Does anyone know what i'm doing wrong or is this a bug?

Comment: Nevermind i've been searching the web for an answer and found out that this feature doesn't work in version 2.2.2 It works since version 2.2.3 which was released 4 days ago but isn't available in maven repositories yet.

Comment: Should have been there for couple of days now: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/fasterxml/jackson/dataformat/jackson-dataformat-csv/2.2.3/

Answer (score 2):

If you want an alternative, use [Open CSV](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/) `CSVWriter`:

```
public CSVWriter(Writer writer, char separator)
```

Comment: Yeah i know. I prefer OpenCSV aswell but a colleague already built the functionality with Jackson so i'll keep it that way.